# Top and bottom borders in table row: only bottom border is styled

Tags: html, css

I'm using the following CSS to achieve a highlighting effect on the table row currently hovered:

```
#container table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
#container table td {
    border: 2px solid white;
}
#container table tr:hover td {
    border-top: 2px solid #999;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #999;
}
```

On all but the top-most tbody row only the bottom border is styled with `#999`. The top row correctly shows two borders. It looks like the white bottom-border of the previous row covers the grey top-border of the hovered one (tested in FF 42). Is there a way to get this right?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pythonpups/4g2w420o/)

Comment: Can you please provide a JSFiddle with a sample table included ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
#container table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
#container table td {
    border-top: 2px solid #FFF;   
}
#container table tr:hover td {
    border-top: 2px solid #999;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #999;
}
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/4g2w420o/5/

Comment: That's it. Thank you very much.

Comment: In chrome on Android, no borders show for me. Do they show for you?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, does it work correctly [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4g2w420o/1/)

```
#container table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
#container table td {
    /*border: 2px solid white; I have commented this */
}
#container table tr:hover td {
    border-top: 2px solid #999;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #999;
}
```

Comment: Like this the table rows/cells don't have a border, so if you hover over them, they kind of shift. That's why I put that part of the CSS there.

Comment: Nice job hmd.  I think you are right. @some-non-descript-user To make the border there, you can make it transparent.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

https://jsfiddle.net/4g2w420o/6/

```
<div id="container">
<table>
    <tr><td>ABC</td><td>DEF</td></tr>
    <tr><td>ABC</td><td>DEF</td></tr>
    <tr><td>ABC</td><td>DEF</td></tr>
</table>
</div>

#container table {
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
#container table tr td {
    border-top: 2px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}
#container table tr:hover td {
    border-top: 2px solid #999;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #999;
}
```

Comment: That's nice. Almost what I intended. But the borders are separated and you can see the shift from one row to the next. I like @Gabriel Augusto's solution better. +1